# AngularJS directives, scopes, magic, and repeating templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So, I'm running Angular.js 1.6.5, and I'm trying to create a "shell" directive as the image<sup>†</sup> below will hopefully help describe.

[image: Example of my "shell" directive in action]
<sub>† — This is just an example of what I'm hoping the final result will represent.
 The image is from my existing work, but all the code is currently written in place with only some of the basic controls wrapped up in directives for re-usability.</sub>

- The blue is the outer scope, an application controller scope/template for an arbitrary page.
- The red is the `<table-view>` "shell" directive, which is intended to provide re-usability of common controls/behaviours.
- The green is the generated content, a table, whose columns are defined by the `<column>` child elements of the `<table-view>` directive.

My objective is to make it such that I can define the `<column>` HTML snippets (and some `<header>` controls perhaps) and the `<table-view>` is responsible for iterating the `records` (bound and watching `$ctrl.users` in this case) and displaying the iterated contents as per the `<column>` definitions.

A caveat is, that the controls (defined in the last columns for example) should be bound to the outer scope (`$ctrl`) with the magic `$record` variable representing the current item in iteration. This is to permit the outer scope to handle what happens when the "View" or "Edit" buttons are clicked for a given `$record`.

The pagination controls would be "baked in" to the `<table-view>` directive, and provide `&`-bound attributes to fire events on the outer scope. This (along with the bound `<header>` controls) allow the outer scope to `$watch` for changes and update the `$ctrl.users` collection on the fly (when search/query options change, or when the page changes)

Anyway, I'm not looking for crowd-sourced code, but I am having trouble figuring out where to start with this. I know there's a lot of magic that can be accomplished between the `template`/`compile`/`link` directive plugs, but I'm needing someone to shove me in the right direction.

---

*Edit @Claies*

> In your question you say that you only have some basic directives for re-usability, but you don't really explain what these "basic directives" are.

That refers to the group-selector, sort-selector, and paginator controls among others. They're great, but they're leaves in the tree; they don't offer transcludability.

> ...the data is typically immutable, and changes at the bottom are only pushed up through the events. The parent component isn't responsible for knowing what the child components are doing, and doesn't watch for the child to change things; instead it waits for the child to tell it that something should be updated.

This is what I'm going for, and the strategy I currently employ; I use `<` bindings wherever possible to read in data, and favour `&` bindings for event driven change notifications to push up changes.

In the example image, the search, group-selector, sort-selector, and pagination controls (in the red) would all invoke change callbacks to the parent scope (the blue), passing back via:

```
onUpdateFilter: '&'
```

It's then the responsibility of the of the parent scope (again, blue) to then update the records in `$ctrl.users` accordingly and that data is passed back into:

```
records: '<'
```

So, in short, the hypothetical directive would exhibit the following scope:

```
scope: {
    records: '<',       // one-way in
    onUpdateFilter: '&' // events out
}
```

The `filter` object, properties of which are bound to the various controls (search, group-selector, etc.) is updated as such:

```
$scope.$watch('$ctrl.filter', updateFilter, true);

function updateFilter() {
    $ctrl.onUpdateFilter({ filter: $ctrl.filter });
}
```

Thus permitting the (blue) containing scope to hook into handle changes of the directive's (red) `filter` changes, re-query the data and pass back in via `records`.

My example showed the transcluded content binding to the outer scope directly (assuming that would be possible) but using the event strategy is just as well.

**The problem** I'm experiencing however, is really just understanding how to handle the various scopes and compilation phases with transclusion.

Comment: I feel like I have to vote to close this as too broad.  I *almost* feel like it's totally off topic as a tutorial request, but it's clear you put some thought into what you want to accomplish;   It's just not clear where anyone could even start offering suggestions, and there isn't really any "broken" code to review....

Comment: I can totally understand that @Claies, I hate asking broad questions so I tried to be specific with intent at least. I'll edit in a few minutes, perhaps I can narrow it down to a non-tutorial question about the relationship between directives, parent scope, and compilation.

Comment: It *seems like* you could accomplish this using the component architecture;  In your question you say that you only have some basic directives for re-usability, but you don't really explain what these "basic directives" are.  I mean, honestly, you already essentially describe the architecture you are trying to achieve, but not the challenges you have with implementing your description.

Comment: If this were a different opinionated framework (ReactJs, as an example) it might be suggested that the best approach is to divide the UI into the smallest pieces you can, and design each piece to operate independently repeatable by accepting all it's data from its parent.  From the top down, data is subdivided at each level, and events are "bubbled up" from the smallest part toward the largest piece responsible for handling the event.

Comment: in this style of design, the data is typically immutable, and changes at the bottom are only pushed up through the events.  The parent component isn't responsible for knowing what the child components are doing, and doesn't watch for the child to change things;  instead it waits for the child to tell it that something should be updated.  In angular, the `=` bindings flag can be equivalent to an upward event; in other words, `$watch` isn't really needed if you are implicitly watching the binding you passed to the child.

Comment: @Claies I've update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost too broad, but I'll try to share my experience in configuring a table.

So my goal was making a dynamic table view, which can be configured using an option, so I don't have to code HTML every time, and I don't have to use a lot of attributes for passing data and callback functions.

```
$scope.tableOptions = {
  search: search, // function (text, skip, take)
  sort: sort, // function (dbName, direction, skip, take)
  columns: [
    {
       name: 'Id', // for header use
       sortable: false,
       dbName: 'id', // for db sorting/filtering use

       // display type 1, only display the data, no need to customize
       data: 'id', // attribute name in json data

       // display type 2, text processing before display
       data: function(data, index, row) {
         return (data / row.total) * 100 + '%';
       }

       // display type 3, pass in template
       dataHtml: "read <span class='red'>now!</span>",

       // display type 4, action
       dataAction: {
         icon: 'glyphicon-edit',
         label: 'Edit',
         callback: editUser // function (row)
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

So table directive would be handling the outer layer such as search and sort function, which is what you are doing already.

Table template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat='column in option.columns'>
      {{column.name}}
      <th-sort option='column'></th-sort>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat='row in data'>
    <column ng-repeat='column in option.columns' option='column' data='row'></column></column>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then column directive will then handle lower layer by component style.